# How to manage changes to state in React Router v6 route actions

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-router-dom, react-context

I'm working on a site with [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) and using [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) to keep track of a JWT for user auth.

I'm trying to make use of React Router's [data routers](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) to handle requests to and from a REST API, i.e. making http requests in route loaders and actions.

I'm having trouble with the rendering behaviour when changing state within React Context and then redirecting inside of a [route action](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action).

I want to be able to respond to a rejected HTTP request in an action by changing the JWT state value in React Context to log out the user and then redirect them to the /login route.

```
// routes/Root.tsx
export const rejectedRootAction = ({ setJwt }: TAuthContext) =>
  async function () {
    // HTTP request to API returning 401 status code
    setJwt(null);
    return redirect("/login");
  };
```

However, when I do this React Router doesn't seem to be updating the JWT in state before attempting to render /login.

/login will itself redirect the user to the root page if the jwt is set, so the user ends up there instead.

I've tried handling login's check on the jwt both inside the component using the context directly and also within a loader, but in both cases the jwt isn't updated in time.

##### [CodeSandbox with a simple version of the code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-test-v3-vv42vf)

Previous experience tells me I may be misunderstanding something fundamental about React Router, but I haven't found useful information on Stack Overflow, Github or the docs.

It seems as if the rendering process is resolving the chain of redirects without considering the change to state I'm making, but that doesn't make sense to me.

I'm not finding anything suggesting that I can't make changes to state within the action.

Can anyone explain or point me to a resource which would clear up where my thought process/approach is flawed?

Comment: Following the reproduction steps in that sandbox's README resulted in getting redirected to the login page, not the home page. Am I misunderstanding the repro or the overall issue? Can you [edit] the post to include the relevant code in a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that it was actually ending up on the /login url. It's still perplexing since it's rendering the home page.

I've been continuing to experiment and fixed that at least, but I think it was a side effect of the same root issue. I've updated the question and code sandbox according to what I've discovered, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer courtesy of [brophdawg11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3524793/brophdawg11) on the Remix Discord.

"You can't use react context/hooks in loaders/actions because fetching is decoupled from the render lifecycle by design so we can avoid render-driven fetch waterfalls"

"Instead of clearing the JWT in react context, you should clear it from it's source of truth (cookie, localsgtorage, etc). - where ever you grab it from to pass it into the context provider"

As such, for my use case I've dropped the use of React Context altogether and am relying on retrieving the token directly from localstorage until I migrate to using cookies.